# Python Diferences between lines of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a lines of strings in a file, I would like to compare theses lines to each other and only print the diferences.
For example these two lines here :

```
4fe6c343554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a
4fe6c470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a
```

i only want to print the odd here :

```
c343
c470
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: But difference is just `343` and `470` !

Comment: how its got from <b> to <p>???

Comment: dont confuse plz post original data

Comment: these are only two lines of a file contains thousands of lines

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to print out the values by structure—e.g., by looking at the contents of the `b` tags?

Comment: c char is the same in both lines, question has a serious flaw

Comment: Also, by "deference" do you mean "difference"? If so, what's the difference between `"aaa111aaa", "aaa222aaa", "bbb333bbb"`? All three whole lines?

Comment: I add the b tag to bold the odds at the original text

Comment: @abarnert yeah thats correct

Comment: @moutamanelbadawi you question is now clear, you siad you have thousand of line, you need to find, odd from that whole, of just pair of lines???

Comment: OK, so in your re-re-edited version, why is the `c` showing up as part of the difference again?

Comment: Meanwhile: Any smart differ (using an algorithm like Ratcliff-Obershelp or any of its successors) is going to tell you that the diff between these two lines is something like: the second one has deleted the `3` before the `4`, then replaced the `3` after the `4` with a `70`. You explicitly want a _dumb_ diff, where strings are compared index by index, so `'abcdefg'` and `'bcdefgh'` are completely unrelated, right?

Comment: @moutamanelbadawi you havent said odds can be any where, if they are at same position slicing is the best solution

Comment: if they are at same position, you can do for all lines, my_string[4:8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a dumb diff (just based on position), [Kasra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545097/908494) is right for your example with only two strings.

However, you say you have many strings. There are many different ways to extend this to multiple strings; from what I can understand, you want each position to count as part of "the odds" in all strings, if any pair of strings anywhere in the list differs at that position.

That's pretty much the same question: you zip the strings up, iterate over the tuples of one character from each string, then unzip the result. But if you have a tuple of N characters, instead of just `i!=j`, how do you check whether any pair is different? Turn it around: If *every* pair is the same, then they're all the same, so if you put them in a set, that set will have one element.

So:

```
>>> strings = '''4fe6c343554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a
... 4fe6c470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a
... 4fe60470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a'''.splitlines()
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(*(chars for chars in zip(*strings) 
...                            if len(set(chars)) != 1))]
['c343', 'c470', '0470']
```

If you've got those strings in a file, just pass the file itself:

```
>>> with open('strings.txt') as f:
...    odds = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*(chars for chars in zip(*f) 
...                                    if len(set(chars)) != 1))]
>>> odds
['c343', 'c470', '0470']
```

Comment: This saves my day, Thank you very much.

Comment: @abarnert Check out my approach and tell me if you like it

Answer (score 1):

As you want the difference the difference is just numbers , that you can use `zip` function to zip the strings together , then you could compare them together :

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(*[(i,j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2) if i!=j])]
['343', '470']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> strings = ['4fe6c343554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a', '4fe6c470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a']
>>> diff = map(str.__ne__, *strings)
>>> [''.join(compress(s, diff)) for s in strings]
['343', '470']
```

For any number of strings

```
>>> strings = ['4fe6c343554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a', '4fe6c470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a', '4fe60470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a']
>>> diff = [len(set(chars)) != 1 for chars in zip(*strings)]
>>> [''.join(compress(s, diff)) for s in strings]
['c343', 'c470', '0470']
```

Comment: Unlike Kasra's answer, this can't be as easily extended to more than 2 strings, because `str.__ne__` obviously can't take 3 or more arguments. You can still obviously do something like `diff = (len(set(chars)) != 1 for chars in zip(*strings))` and then use `compress`, but at that point it doesn't see as clever anymore.

Comment: true i just noticed this

Comment: Still, it does seem more readable for the two-string version, even if it's a bit longer. (At least to me, but then I always like passing unbound methods to `map`, and relying on its implicit zipping; not everyone does…)

Comment: @abarnert i agree, yes its a plausible approach even checking `len(set(chars)) != 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = r'4fe6c343554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a'
b = r'4fe6c470554c51454e503249393954564837304d4c323330513254524e49500a'

print ''.join((v for k,v in enumerate(a) if b[k] != v)) #343
print ''.join((v for k,v in enumerate(b) if a[k] != v)) #470
```